# Snowflake - using json_parse and select distinct to un-nested column and compare with another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 columns, 1 is a nested column named `custom_field` and the other is `sales_id` I want to compare the `sales_id_2` values in `custom_field` with `sales_id` column

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
    select distinct parse_json(custom_fields) as CUSTOM_FIELDS 
from my_table where custom_fields:sales_id_2 = sales_id;
```

but I get the error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 111 Invalid argument
> types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(2)).

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| custom_field              |      sales_id           |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|                           |                         |
|   {                       |   235324115             |
|  "sales_id_2": 235324115, |   1234351               |
|     "g": 12,              |                         |
|     "r": 255              |                         |
|   }                       |                         |
|   {                       |   678322341             |
|  "sales_id_2": 1234351,   |   5648561               |
|     "g": 13,              |                         |
|     "r": 254              |                         |
|   }                       |                         |
```

I'm hoping to see empty results, because I believe sales_id_2 is the same as sales_id

Answer (score 0):

`::` is for casting, plus you are trying a JSON operation on a varchar column.  try this

`select distinct parse_json(custom_fields) as CUSTOM_FIELDS  from my_table where parse_json(custom_fields):sales_id_2 = sales_id;`

Comment: Sorry I did have only 1 colon not 2 in my query, I've updated the question. Also, Since my custom_fields column has multiple nested values its returning all of those values for instance (from the table above) its returning rows that look like this {"g": 12,  "r": 255  }. etc..

Comment: Can you update the question with the result you want to produce?

Comment: I've updated the question with the results I'm hoping to see, thanks for responding!